# How to use the value of a pfobject outside of the query

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm a first time developer and I'm starting out in objective C and parse. I understand how to post data to a pfclass, I understand how to retrieve the data in a pfquery, but what I am unclear on is how to take that data from a query and use it elsewhere in the app.

The example I am using is related to a survey app I am creating.

When a user selects a survey answer

The app posts the category, the question, and the answer that was chosen by the user to my **first** pfclass.

```
NSString *quizString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded];
NSString *questionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected];
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"];

PFObject *newAnswerVote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizData"];
newAnswerVote[@"quiz"] = quizString;
newAnswerVote[@"question"] = questionString;
newAnswerVote[@"answer"] = answerString;

[newAnswerVote saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded == YES){
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

Then I go to my **second** class, and query the exact result this user has selected and add an additional increment to it's tally. This way I have a record of how many times this answer has been chosen by all users.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[query whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[query whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[query whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *Total, NSError *error){
    [Total incrementKey:@"Total"];

    [Total saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){
        }
        else{
        };
```

Here's where I am stuck. What I need is for the app to determine the total votes for each of 4 possible answers in this specific question and survey. Then I want the app to determine which answer has the most votes, and then have two separate outcomes based on whether the user picked the most voted answer or not.

Now, I'm not looking for any one to spell all those functions out in code for me, but if you could help me understand how I take the result of a PFQuery and turn it into an integer value that the app can understand once the query is complete I think I can get the rest of it figured out.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit -----------**

Got it all solved. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you had to do the following:
After the value of `Total` has been incremented, you had to find the answer with the highest `Total`.
You could use something like:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[query whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[query whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[query whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *total, NSError *error){
    [total incrementKey:@"Total"];
    NSUInteger myVote = total[@"Total"];

    [total saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){
            PFQuery *queryForHighestVote = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
            [queryForHighestVote orderByDescending:@"Total"];
            [queryForHighestVote getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *firstAnswerStorageObject, NSError *error){
                if (nil != error) {
                    // query failed
                } else {
                    NSUInteger highestVote = firstAnswerStorageObject[@"Total"];
                    if (myVote == highestVote) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
        }
        else {
            // Increment not saved
        }
```

PS: I changed `Total` to `total`, since variables usually start with LC characters, while classes start with UC characters.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Comment: I ran into an expression error, I've updated my code in my question, any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, Thank you for your help, this was exactly the info I needed!

Comment: Hello again, you were very helpful with this. I was wondering if you wouldnt mind helping me with another question I had on a more complicated block of code similar to this. I've posed the question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123298/pf-query-not-returning-results?noredirect=1#comment55996354_34123298

Thanks!