# PF Query Not Returning Results

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm really confused as to why my PFQuery wont return any results. Let me start by showing you what I originally did, **this code worked perfectly.**

```
-(IBAction)Answer2:(id)sender{

NSString *quizString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded];
NSString *questionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected];
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"];

PFObject *newAnswerVote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizData"];
newAnswerVote[@"quiz"] = quizString;
newAnswerVote[@"question"] = questionString;
newAnswerVote[@"answer"] = answerString;

[newAnswerVote saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded == YES){

        [newAnswerVote incrementKey:@"Total"];
    }
    else{
    }
}
 ];


PFQuery *queryb = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryb whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"]];
[queryb getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *total, NSError *error){
    [total incrementKey:@"Total"];

    NSString *myVote = total[@"Answer"];

    [total saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){
            PFQuery *queryForHighestVoteb = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
            [queryForHighestVoteb whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
            [queryForHighestVoteb whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
            [queryForHighestVoteb orderByDescending:@"Total"];
            [queryForHighestVoteb getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *firstAnswerStorageObject, NSError *error){
                if (nil != error) {
                    // query failed
                } else {
                    NSString *highestVote = firstAnswerStorageObject[@"Answer"];
                    if (myVote == highestVote) {

                        [self RightAnswer];
                    } else {

                        [self WrongAnswer];

                    }}}];

        }}];
}];
}
```

Now this is the code I am working with now. Using the same PFQuery used previously, but with added arithmetic used later on. However, this query will not retrieve any results. Leaving me with 0 values for VoteAScore, VoteBScore, VoteCScore, and VoteDScore. Leaving me with the error:

EXC_arithmetic (code=exc_i386_div, subcode=0x0)

I have no idea what's causing it.

```
-(void)GetTotalVotes{

PFQuery *querya = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[querya whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[querya whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[querya whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"]];
[querya getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *atotal, NSError *error){

    [atotal incrementKey:@"Total"];
    [atotal incrementKey:@"Test"];


    [atotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){

            NSUInteger answerATotal = [atotal[@"Total"]intValue];

            VoteAScore = answerATotal;


            [atotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded == YES){
                }
                else{}
            }];}

        else{}
    }];}];

PFQuery *queryb = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryb whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryb whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"]];
[queryb getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *btotal, NSError *error){

    [btotal incrementKey:@"Total"];
    [btotal incrementKey:@"Test"];


    [btotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){

            NSUInteger answerBTotal = [btotal[@"Total"]intValue];

            VoteBScore = answerBTotal;


            [btotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded == YES){
                }
                else{}
            }];}

        else{}
    }];}];

PFQuery *queryc = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryc whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryc whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryc whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c"]];
[queryc getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *ctotal, NSError *error){

    [ctotal incrementKey:@"Total"];
    [ctotal incrementKey:@"Test"];


    [ctotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){

            NSUInteger answerCTotal = [ctotal[@"Total"]intValue];

            VoteCScore = answerCTotal;



            [ctotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded == YES){
                }
                else{}
            }];}

        else{}
    }];}];

PFQuery *queryd = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[queryd whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[queryd whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[queryd whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"d"]];
[queryd getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *dtotal, NSError *error){

    [dtotal incrementKey:@"Total"];
    [dtotal incrementKey:@"Test"];


    [dtotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){

        NSUInteger answerDTotal = [dtotal[@"Total"]intValue];

        VoteDScore = answerDTotal;

        AllVoteScore = VoteAScore + VoteBScore + VoteCScore + VoteDScore;

        [dtotal saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded == YES){
            }
            else{}
        }];}

        else{}
    }];}];}







-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender{


NSString *quizString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded];
NSString *questionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected];
NSString *answerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"];

PFObject *newAnswerVote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizData"];
newAnswerVote[@"quiz"] = quizString;
newAnswerVote[@"question"] = questionString;
newAnswerVote[@"answer"] = answerString;

[newAnswerVote saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded == YES){
    }
    else{
    }
}
 ];


PFQuery *querym = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
[querym whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
[querym whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
[querym whereKey:@"Answer" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"]];
[querym getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *total, NSError *error)    {
    [total incrementKey:@"Total"];
    [total incrementKey:@"Test"];


    [total saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded == YES){
            PFQuery *queryForHighestVotec = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AnswerStorage"];
            [queryForHighestVotec whereKey:@"Quiz" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",CategoryLoaded]];
            [queryForHighestVotec whereKey:@"Question" equalTo: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",QuestionSelected]];
            [queryForHighestVotec orderByDescending:@"Total"];
            [queryForHighestVotec getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *firstAnswerStorageObject, NSError *error){
                if (nil != error) {
                    // query failed
                } else {


                    [self GetTotalVotes];}
            }];
        }}];
}];





if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteBScore > VoteCScore || VoteBScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 0;
}

else if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteCScore > VoteBScore || VoteCScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 1;

}

else if (VoteAScore > VoteBScore || VoteAScore > VoteCScore || VoteAScore > VoteDScore || VoteDScore > VoteBScore || VoteDScore > VoteCScore){

    Outcome = 2;


}

else if (VoteBScore > VoteAScore || VoteBScore > VoteCScore || VoteBScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 3;

}

else if (VoteCScore > VoteAScore || VoteCScore > VoteBScore || VoteCScore > VoteDScore){

    Outcome = 4;

}

else if (VoteDScore > VoteAScore || VoteDScore > VoteBScore || VoteDScore > VoteCScore){

    Outcome = 5;

}
switch (Outcome)
{
    case 0:

    OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
    TwoFraction = VoteBScore/AllVoteScore;
    Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
    InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

    AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;

    [self RightAnswer];

        break;

    case 1:

        OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteCScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

        ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;


    [self RightAnswer];

        break;


    case 2:

        OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteDScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddScore;

    [self RightAnswer];

        break;

    case 3:

        OneFraction = VoteBScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

    case 4:

        OneFraction = VoteCScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

    case 5:

        OneFraction = VoteDScore/AllVoteScore;
        TwoFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;
        Margin = OneFraction - TwoFraction;
        InvertedMargin = 1 - Margin;

        AddScore = Margin * 1000;

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber - AddScore;

    [self WrongAnswer];

        break;

}}
```

Comment: The first two queries are not the same as the second two.  The first two match "Answer" to @"a" and the second two to @"b".  That would explain the differing results.

Comment: It still does the same even if it goes to "b". I have 4 of these, one going to a, one going to b, one to c, and one to d. The first code works for any of those 4 options, but in the second block none of them work.

Comment: You're supposed to give us a *minimal* example exhibiting your issue. I don't think 298 lines qualifies for minimal.

Comment: The `EXC_arithmetic (code=exc_i386_div, subcode=0x0)` error is most probably due to the division by zero here: `OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;`. Even if your query were working correctly, you most certainly need to handle this case.

Comment: Why are you saving `atotal` twice consecutively?

Comment: Why are you repeating the same code for Answer = a, Answer = b, Answer = c? There's this magic thing called a loop: `for (NSString *answer in @[@"a", @"b", @"c"]) { ...}`, you know.

Comment: right exactly, why does it think that this

OneFraction = VoteAScore/AllVoteScore;

is a division by zero?

and thank you for pointing out the typo with atotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the many, many issues in your code (see comments above), you'll have to keep in mind that `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:`, as its name implies, works in the background. So when it returns control to its caller, nothing has happened, and only later will the block be called with the results.

So you can't consider that because that call returned, the block has been called, and data that it returns is already available and saved (that will happen later).

You either need to use the sync versions of the `PFQuery` calls (but this will block your UI if you call them from the main thread), or, better, include any logic that relies on the results of those calls in the provided block, not in code running after those calls.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. Also..a little harsh. But I appreciate the help, I've just started learning this stuff so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked me in a comment to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035118/how-to-use-the-value-of-a-pfobject-outside-of-the-query/34037312?noredirect=1#comment55997117_34037312) to suggest a solution to this question, here is my answer:

jcaron is right:  Your code is sending multiple queries to Parse, and is using the return variables before they are set by the callbacks. Thus they are zero and you get a divide by zero exception.
The part of your code where you evaluate the results of the queries can only be executed after **all** queries have completed.

You could use 2 approaches:

**1) Nesting queries sequentially**
In your main thread, issue only `querya`. In the callback of `querya` (if it succeeds), issue `queryb`, and so on, and finally in the callback of your last query, evaluate your results.
This would work, but the code will look confusing due to the nesting over multiple levels, and it is slow because the queries are issued sequentially.

**2) Executing the queries concurrently**
Define a method to evaluate your results, because it could be called now from different parts of the code. It must be called as soon as **all** queries have executed their callbacks.
In your main thread, setup a variable `__block NSUInteger nrOfExpectedServerResponses` and set it to the number of queries that you will execute concurrently. Then issue your queries one after the other (like in your code) in the main thread.
Although you issue the queries in a certain order, the callbacks can be called in any order (or not at all, if you loose connectivity). Thus, any callback of your queries may be the last callback.
To check, which one is actually the last one, you can decrement `nrOfExpectedServerResponses` in each callback, and when it reaches zero in a certain callback, your method to evaluate the results is executed from this callback.
However you should be aware that this is asynchronous code, and its parts can more or less be executed any time. For example, a statement `nrOfExpectedServerResponses--` is not atomic, and if 2 of these statements are executed „at the same time“ in 2 callbacks, `nrOfExpectedServerResponses` may not have been decremented by 2, but only by 1. To avoid such hazards, you have to enclose this statement be a `@synchronized` block, e.g. `@synchronized(self){…}`.

In both cases, of course, you had to handle all possible errors. You could, e.g. setup a timeout timer that let your app continue if the queries do not finish within a reasonable time.

Comment: Thank you both so much! After the advice you gave me I got it all sorted out. Then I redid everything and made the code much more efficient after it all clicked. its much better now. Thank you both for taking the time to go through it all!